# Specify Jacoco Version from Command Line when Running Maven Release

Tags: maven, version, jacoco

I have a need to specify jacoco dependency/plugin version from the command line when running the following command:

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform ...options... [JACOCO VERSION]
```

Basically, I want all projects to be built using the same jacoco version despite whatever version is present in their pom.

Is there a way to do this through the cli? I have seen examples doing this when specifying jacoco prepare agent, but I want to specify the actual `jacoco-maven-plugin` plugin version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the version inside the `properties` and set value from the command line.

For eg,

```
    <properties>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.9</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

While from the command line, specify the new property value.

```
mvn -Djacoco-maven-plugin.version=0.8.5
```

You can also verify the effective pom by running

```
mvn -Djacoco-maven-plugin.version=0.8.5 help:effective-pom
```

Comment: That is awesome! And exactly what I was scouring the internet for but could not find.